# HttpTransport ksoap call multiple functions

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to call 2 functions setUserName() and setPassword() from Android client use ksoap2 to check user login:

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) 
{
    this.userName = userName;
}

    public boolean isCorrect(){
            if(this.userName.equals("abc") && this.password.equals("xyz"))
    return true;
            else
            return false;
}
```

On the client app I want to setUserName() and setPassword() then call isCorrect() function but I'm not successful. When I call isCorrect(), username and password are still null.

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"setUserId", envelope);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"setPassword", envelope);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"isCorrect", envelope);
```

Please tell me the solution for this case.
Thanks,

Add more code:

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "setUserName");
    // Set Username
    PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
    unamePI.setName("userName");
    unamePI.setValue(userName);
    unamePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(unamePI);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"setUserName", envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "setPassword");
    // Set Password
    PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
    passPI.setName("password");
    passPI.setValue(password);
    passPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passPI);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"setPassword", envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "isCorrect");

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"isCorrect", envelope);
        // Get the response
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://ws.webapp.org" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://ws.webapp.org">
    <wsdl:documentation>
        Please Type your service description here
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.webapp.org">
            <xs:element name="setUserName">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="setPassword">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="isCorrect">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="isCorrectResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="getUserName">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="getUserNameResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="getPassword">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="getPasswordResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getUserNameRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getUserName"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getUserNameResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getUserNameResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="setUserNameRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:setUserName"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getPasswordRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getPassword"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getPasswordResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:getPasswordResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="setPasswordRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:setPassword"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="isCorrectRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:isCorrect"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="isCorrectResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:isCorrectResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="HelloPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="getUserName">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:getUserNameRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:getUserName"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:getUserNameResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getUserNameResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setUserName">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:setUserNameRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:setUserName"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPassword">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:getPasswordRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:getPassword"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:getPasswordResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getPasswordResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setPassword">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:setPasswordRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:setPassword"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="isCorrect">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:isCorrectRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:isCorrect"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:isCorrectResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:isCorrectResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="HelloSoap11Binding" type="ns:HelloPortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getUserName">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getUserName" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setUserName">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:setUserName" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPassword">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getPassword" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setPassword">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:setPassword" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="isCorrect">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:isCorrect" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="HelloSoap12Binding" type="ns:HelloPortType">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getUserName">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:getUserName" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setUserName">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:setUserName" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPassword">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:getPassword" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setPassword">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:setPassword" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="isCorrect">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:isCorrect" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="HelloHttpBinding" type="ns:HelloPortType">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getUserName">
            <http:operation location="getUserName"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setUserName">
            <http:operation location="setUserName"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPassword">
            <http:operation location="getPassword"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="setPassword">
            <http:operation location="setPassword"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="isCorrect">
            <http:operation location="isCorrect"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Hello">
        <wsdl:port name="HelloHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloSoap11Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/testwebservice/services/Hello.HelloHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="HelloHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloSoap12Binding">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/testwebservice/services/Hello.HelloHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="HelloHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:HelloHttpBinding">
            <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/testwebservice/services/Hello.HelloHttpEndpoint/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I am doubtful, how are you calling different operations using same soap action and same envelope in a sequence. Can you paste more code and elaborate your implemenation steps here.

Comment: I know my code is not correct so I'm just asking how I can pass the value userName and password before calling isCorrect()
Thanks,

Comment: Are you importing any wsdl and generating these classes and methods?

Comment: yes I did, I tried to call getUserName() method and it worked. The thing is I cannot pass userName and password at the same time

Comment: ok , one more thing, please paste your wsdl binding here for these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Set Action appropriately for different methods call as Namspace/Action or whatever you followed for setting setUserName SOAP_ACTION till now.

as per your wsdl,

for setUserName,

```
 SOAP_ACTION="http://ws.webapp.org/setUserName";
```

for setPassword.

```
SOAP_ACTION="http://ws.webapp.org/setPassword";
```

for isCorrect

SOAP_ACTION="http://ws.webapp.org/isCorrect";

Comment: When I called different methods, I call as Namespace/Action:


SOAP_ACTION="http://ws.webapp.org/" ;
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"setUserName", envelope);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"setPassword", envelope);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"isCorrect", envelope);

Comment: You need to put different soap action as mentioned in your wsdl:Binding for different operations. Just give it a try if it doesn't resolve then we will proceed further.Also let me know if u receive any error.